JavaScript IntelliSense on React component sub-functions does not work
PS: yes, I already tested many configurations and things I found here, like this topic: VSCode Intellisense, snippets, suggestions are not working in JSX, TSX files
None of them are reporting exactly my case, and also nothing I tried solved the issue (not even sure if IS an issue or just a limitation)
The "issue"
I noted that no matter what, the IntelliSense only works on some particular places inside a React file (JS or JSX, doesn't matter)
Check the image below:

As you can see, it seems that IntelliSense only engages when it detects the JS properly, inside a return. But for some reason the exact same method inside a function declaration at the top has no widget/tooltip, and neither the autocomplete/autosuggests work.

I checked the built-in extension, it's enabled. I restarted it for good measure, no change.
I tested multiple configurations and extensions, most are related to full file support from years ago (nowadays, the support is native)
I tested restarting VS Code in "safe mode" and reset all my settings.json, same behavior.

Hopefully anyone has any tips on how to get this working - maybe a config I don't know, maybe a custom extension, not sure.
Thanks

Look at the 'e' type in onChange handler (mouse over it)
Then put that type in the function that you created
const textChange: (e: /* here paste the type */) => {

...


Typescript can't infer where your function will be used so you need to define the type of your params
The types or (inference/intellisense) that you are getting are there because there are some TS files that are checked under the hood


In this case for onChange React prop it finds that in
node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts
And for event values that are declared in onChange (inline)
node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.dom.d.ts

Yeah, that "works", but I'm not using TypeScript on this project/file. Any way to solve this for JSX files?

Not really, Intellisense is most made for TS there is no way to infer things only using JS (internally it tries to infer but it's very basic because doesn't have explicit types)

Another thing to add is that you get some guidance related to props or event types because there are typescript files that are checked under the hood for react and events

yeah, I figure this would be the case, that's why I mention if is really an issue or just a limitation.  I will select your reply as answer then, at least we know that when using TS it works.
